# Show that $y = c_1+c_2t^{1/2}$ won't always solve $yy''+(y')^2=0$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Show that $y = c_1+c_2t^{1/2}$ doesn't always solve the differential equation

$$yy''+(y')^2=0$$

that's what I did:

$$yy''+(y')^2=  \left(c_1+\frac{c_2}{2}t^{-1/2}\right)\left(-\frac{c_2}{4}t^{-3/2}\right)+\left( \frac{c_2}{2}t^{-1/2}\right)^2 = $$

$$-c_1\frac{c_2}{4}t^{-3/2}-\frac{c_2^2}{8}t^{-2}+\frac{c_2^2}{4}t^{-1}$$

but I can t even group the therm to see when they'll sum to $0$. What should I do?

**Also, why this doesn't contradict the theorem that says that if $y_1$ and $y_2$ are solutions of a diferential equation, then $c_1y_1+c_2y_2$ is also a solution?**

Comment: Because superposition principle only holds for linear ode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **almost** got the answer: $y y'' + (y')^2$ is an expression in $t$ that does not simplify to $0$ (except your expression is not quite right), so this is not a solution to the differential equation.  What you should have obtained was $-c_1 c_2/(4 t^{3/2})$.

BTW, it turns out that the general solution of this one is
$$ y = \pm \sqrt{c_1 + c_2 t}$$

Answer (score 1):

when you set

$$ \frac{y^\prime}{y} =-\frac{y^{\prime \prime}}{y\prime} =c_1$$

it suggests chain rule of a product

$${y^\prime}{y} = c_1$$

which integrates to

$$y^2 = c_2+ 2 c_1\,x$$

Taking square root for both terms at normal speed you get

$$y =  \sqrt{c_2+ 2 c_1\,x} $$

but at higher speeds the first term gets excluded :)

$$y =  c_2+ \sqrt{c_3\,x} $$

It is a parabola with a constant subnormal length $c_1.$

Answer (score 0):

Since Jacky answered the bolded question [in the comment on the OP], I'll answer the main one: you are basically done.

If $c_1+c_2t^{1/2}$ always solved the DE, it would in particular have to solve it when $t=1$ for every $c_1$ and $c_2$. But when $t=1$, then $yy''+(y')^2=(1/8)(-2c_1c_2-c_2^2+2c_2^2)$. This is not zero for every choice of $c_1$ and $c_2$; for instance, if $c_1=c_2=1$ it is $-1/8$.

Answer (score 0):

If $$y=a+b \sqrt{t}\implies y'=\frac{b}{2 \sqrt{t}}\implies y''=-\frac{b}{4 t^{3/2}}$$ $$y y'' +(y')^2=-\frac{a b}{4 t^{3/2}}$$ So, if the rhs has to be $0$ either $(a=0, b\neq 0)$ or $(b=0, a\neq 0)$ or $(a=0,b=0)$.